# How to run Playbook for multiple servers/host in same environment

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am writing a Ansible playbook which i need to run for my preprod environment. Now deployment on this environment is a bit tricky. There are multiple wars which gets deployed on multiple servers. This environment consist of 4 different application and servers and the deployment needs to be done sequentially -.
Also I am thinking of using roles. For example suppose there are 3 tasks copy the release, stop the tomcat, deploy the release so there will be three separate roles doing this activity.

cms-server
db-server
front-server
api-server.

I am trying to understand how do i build inventory for this? I am using group_vars to define a set of variables for a particular group.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you?

```
preprod:
  children: 
    cms-server: 
      hosts: 
        serv1
        serv2
    db-server:
      hosts:
        serv3
    front-server:
      hosts:
        serv4
    api-server:
        serv5
        serv6
```

The "children" here indicates that the following are sub-groups. "Hosts" are for the hosts inside the sub-groups.

You can then have groups_vars files for every group (will apply to any host inside that group) or also on the preprod group, which may allow you to replicate this for prod or dev envs in the future.

If you decide to follow this, I would suggest you rename your group names and add an "s" at servers.

Comment: Thanks For your quick response however I have some query. My main yml looks something like below  and the target_env I am passing from the command line. Now this target env could be preprod, prod etc.

In group_vars, can i just have preprod.yml OR prod.yml and i define all the variables of all the hosts in that. Will that work?
For example - /group_vars/preprod.yml, /group_var/prod.yml

Please provide your view

`---
# file: main.yml
- name: Deploy Application to tomcat nodes
  hosts: '{{ target_env }}'
  roles:
    - role: repodownload
      tags:
        - repodownload
    -`

Comment: If I understand properly your question, I'd say it would probably work yes. Another way of going around this would be to have 2 playbooks, calling the same role with different hosts (prod and preprod). I see another alternative too, it would be to have 1 playbook with the two hosts blocks and roles invocation and adding a ```when``` condition, such as ```when 'preprod' in target_env ``` https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement

Comment: Hi Bruno, when condition could help.
May be i have not put it the right way. Let me rephrase it. I have posted another one -

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60884419/how-to-define-group-var-for-multiple-host-in-same-environment